# Jquery how to remove trigger() method after click button

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, eventtrigger

I'm working with laravel pagination inside a bootstrap modal, I want the modal to stay open everytime I change the pagination page, and I think I solved it, but when i click the close button of the modal i want the trigger() method deleted, here is my code :

```html
  {{-- Modal daftar pengumuman --}}
    <div class="modal fade" id="daftarPengumuman" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Semua postingan</h1>
            <button type="button" class="pengumuman_close btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            @if ($announcements->count())
                @foreach ($announcements as $pengumuman)
                <ul class="list-group mb-4 btn3d text-center">
                  <li class="list-group-item bg-warning">{{ $pengumuman->judul }}.</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">{{ $pengumuman->category_id }}.</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">{{ $pengumuman->pesan }}.</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item"><img src="/imgs/kentang.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" style="width: 150px; height:100px"></li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">{{ $pengumuman->durasi }} Hari.</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">
                    @if ($pengumuman->user_id == 0)
                        {{ $pengumuman->nama_admin }}
                    @else 
                        {{ $pengumuman->user_id }}
                    @endif
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-center"><a href="#" type="button" class="button text-decoration-none w-50"><span>Design partisipan</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                @endforeach

                <div id="paginator">
                  {{ $announcements->links() }}
                </div>
            @endif
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="pengumuman_close btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JQUERY CODE :

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   
    //if paginator click
    if({{ request('page') }}){
      $('#btn_pengumuman').trigger('click'); //trigger the modal button

    //when close button of modal click, unbind trigger method
     $('.pengumuman_close').click(function(){
      $('#btn_pengumuman').unbind('trigger')
     })
     }})
```

but when i click close button of modal the trigger method is not deleted, is it because trigger() is not one of the event handlers? what is the best way to solve this please help sensei.
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what is being asked here. You code here calls `trigger` when the document is ready. This happens only once per page load

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. There are jQuery Event Delegation methods, like `.on('click', ...)`, which can be unbound via `.off('click', ...)`, or as a one-time call via `.once('click', ...)`, but I'm not sure if/how that would apply here. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your refferences, i'm just learning jquery, yup the trigger runs once per page load, but when I try to submit a form on the same page, the modal will always appear after the page is reloaded, so I try to remove the trigger when the close button from the modal is clicked

Comment: When the modal closes you need to somehow remove the `page` query parameter from the next request because your `trigger` is executed  if that parameter exists. Not sure how easy or hard that will be for you it depends what links you expect to follow after closing the modal

Comment: I didn't understand either what you're trying to accomplish, however, you could add an event.preventDefault(); like this `$('.pengumuman_close').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
      $('#btn_pengumuman').unbind('trigger')
     })`

Comment: okay, thanks for your answers guys, I'll be happy to try implementing it, maybe in short I want the modal to automatically re-open after I click on the page number in the paginator, but on the same view page I have several input forms, so as apokyrfos said the modal will always open automatically if the 'page' request is still available, so I try to remove the trigger() method if I click the close button on the modal, so I expect the modal not to appear when submitting the form on the same view page, sorry if my question isn't clear, thank you